# stacked bar chart in dimple.js

Tags: d3.js, dimple.js

I'm new to `dimple.js` and `d3`. For one of my test execution reporting tool, I need to show a chart that depicts the execution status. This chart should be of type `stacked bar chart`.

My sample data is as below,

```
var data = [{
                "run-id": 25,
                "TotalCount": 100,
                "Pass": 50,
                "Fail": 30,
                "Skip": 20
        }, {
               "run-id": 26,
                "TotalCount": 50,
                "Pass": 35,
                "Fail": 15,
                "Skip": 5
        }, {
               "run-id": 27,
                "TotalCount": 60,
                "Pass": 40,
                "Fail": 5,
                "Skip": 15
        }];
```

I want to have the output chart as a stacked bar chart with 3 bars(for above data), one for each run ids. Also individual count(pass|fail|skip) should be written in its bar chart area(inside)

I'm new to dimple.js and in ramp up phase. Tried following solution, but that didn't work.

```
chart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
chart.addCategoryAxis("x", "run-id");
chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "TotalCount");
series = chart.addSeries(["Pass", "Fail","Skip"], dimple.plot.bar);
chart.draw()
```

Can anyone help/hint me to move forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you have to format your data, so you it can generate stack bar. I attached updated version of your data and created stacked bar for you.
[check here for writing value in bar](http://dimplejs.org/advanced_examples_viewer.html?id=advanced_bar_labels)

[StackBar](http://jsbin.com/joputo/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Thanks Mahmut, correcting the elements in data structure, did the trick !

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. I am fairly new with dimple.js and still trying to learn.